# Load Crystal Report ReportDocument vs CrystalReportVIewerDirectly

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

What is advantage and lack between load Crystal Report via CrystalReportViewer directly and ReportDocument?


I can use both of them, loading Crystal Report directly, using some path, and loading Crystal Report via ReportDocument first. In certain case, wich one is better? Where is the better performance? Or, it's just style in coding?


Sory for this kind of question.

Comment: Do you mean double clicking a report to open it in the Designer, versus opening the designer and then the report by file->open-> report? If so, I can think of no difference. Is there a reason why you think there could be?